# React Is Not Rendering

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, web, babeljs

I have been stuck with this problem of react not rendering since a few weeks now, it used to work fine before...

***index.js***          // Note -> Has Been Bundled with babel-loader

```
    import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    
    const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
    root.render(
    <h1>
      Hello, world!
    </h1>
    );
```

***webpack.config.js***

```
    const path = require("path");
    // const config = require("./package.json");
    
    module.exports = {
      target: 'web',
      mode: 'production',
      module: {
        rules: [
          { test: /\.js$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
          { test: /\.jsx$/, use: 'babel-loader' },
          { test: /\.css$/, use: 'css-loader' },
          { test: /\.json$/, use: 'json-loader'},
          { test: /\.(png|jpe?g|webp|ttf|eot|svg|gif)$/, use: 'file-loader'},
        ],
      },
      entry: "./Src/index.js", 
      devtool: "source-map", 
      output: {
        path: __dirname,  
        filename: './Public/JavaScript/Webpack/index.js',
      }
    }
```

***babel.config.json***

```
    {
      "presets": ["@babel/preset-env", "@babel/preset-react"],
      "plugins": []
    }
```

***package.json***

```
    {
     ...
      "dependencies": {
        "@emotion/react": "^11.10.4",
        "@emotion/styled": "^11.10.4",
        "@mui/icons-material": "^5.10.3",
        "@mui/material": "^5.10.3",
        "@tauri-apps/api": "^1.0.2",
        "axios": "^0.27.2",
        "cassandra-driver": "^4.6.4",
        "clsx": "^1.2.1",
        "framer-motion": "^7.2.1",
        "react": "^18.2.0",
        "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
        "react-helmet": "^6.1.0",
        "react-router-dom": "^6.3.0"
      },
      "devDependencies": {
        "@babel/cli": "^7.18.10",
        "@babel/core": "^7.18.13",
        "@babel/preset-env": "^7.18.10",
        "@babel/preset-react": "^7.18.6",
        "@electron/get": "^2.0.0",
        "@tauri-apps/cli": "^1.0.5",
        "babel-loader": "^8.2.5",
        "css-loader": "^6.7.1",
        "electron": "^20.1.1",
        "file-loader": "^6.2.0",
        "jest": "^29.0.2",
        "json-loader": "^0.5.7",
        "webpack": "^5.74.0",
        "webpack-cli": "^4.10.0"
      }
    }
```

***index.html***

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en-GB">

  <head>
    
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge" />
    <title>Hello, World!</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="./JavaScript/Console.js"></script>
    
  </head>

  <body>

    <!-- ... -->
    <div id="root"></div>

    <!-- ... -->
    <scirpt src="./JavaScript/Webpack/index.js"></scirpt>

  </body>
  
</html>
```

Surprisingly, React Dev Tools also doesn't detect React in here, Nor do I get any errors in the Console.

**I've tried the following solutions ->**

1. Reinstalling all dependencies with Npm
2. Cloning other projects to find out whether it works with them (It Does)
3. Re-checking File names, paths etc...
4. Browsing the web for solutions

Please don't hesitate to request, if you need extra information.

[Blank page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wmjoE.png)

Comment: I do not see any wrong with your code. In your mean, how is it not rendering? Could you provide more steps when you run the app and the result in the browser?

Comment: The result in the browser is nothing rather than a blank page. Surprisingly, React Dev Tools also doesn't detect React working in there :(

Comment: Could you provide the Elements' Dev tool picture of that blank page?  We need to know whether the `index.html` file was rendered. So we could know where the problem comes from.

Comment: A blank page is usually accompanied by errors in the browser console

Comment: The Console is totally clear...

Comment: After 3 intense hours of debugging, I realized that somehow index.js doesn't show up in the elements tab, I copy-pasted the code from index.js to Console.js and it finally worked. All-tough the path is correct I'm wondering why isn't it appearing.